# Changing file paths using third party apps

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, mobile-application

I am writing an mobile app using Flutter. I want to change some of the default file paths existing in my device.
For example, whenever I click a picture using my phone, it is stored in the default folder.

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera
```

I want to change the default file path so when I click a photo, it gets stored in a location of my choice.

Is there anyway I can do that using Flutter?

Comment: `For example, whenever I click a picture using my phone,` You mean: whenever i take a picture using my phones default Camera app?

Comment: `For example, whenever I click a picture using my phone, ` What does that have to do with your app?

Comment: `when I click a photo, it gets stored in a location of my choice.` Whenever you click a photo it is already stored in your device i would think.

Comment: You have to explain a lot.

Comment: Yes. I want to store the pictures in my phone in a folder other than the default one. And yes, using the default Camera App.

Comment: You did not explain enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can do that using Flutter?

No. There is no way of doing that without Flutter, either.

Where a camera app stores its photos is up to the developers of that camera app. That may be in the location that you specified. It may be somewhere else on the device. It may be not on the device at all, but instead sent directly to a server. Regardless, other apps do not get to control that behavior for when the user uses the camera app directly.

If *your app* is asking a camera app to take a picture using an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, you can request that the camera app store the resulting photo in a particular location, using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.